# Breaking out of Try/Except While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I have a while loop which check if the ticker exists if it does not it allows the user to try again but at the same time if the use types exit it would quit the program. Here the code

```
ticker = input("Ticker : ")
while True:
    try:
        web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo',start, end)
        print('Ticker exists')
    except Exception as e:
        responce = input('That Ticker does not exist. Try Again? Type exit to quit')
        if responce.lower() == exit:
            break
        else:
            pass
```

I am not able to get it to break when you type exit.

Comment: The response the user typed in might possibly be equal to `"exit"`, a string.  It will certainly never be equal to `exit`, a built-in object that displays a message if you print it, or exits the Python interpreter if you call it.

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown i tagged python to the question!

Comment: I see the tag was added since I asked.  Well done.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `exit` is also an implementation detail of CPython, not something guaranteed to be defined. (An implementation without `exit` would raise a `NameError`, making the problem obvious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = input('That Ticker does not exist. Try Again? Type exit to quit')
    if response.lower() == "exit":
        break
```

You're just missing quotes around the word "exit"